# Sql Select Where Like with Exception

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I got in my database several rows which include dates + information.

For example:

```
    Col 01

    01.01.2013: play video games
    01.01.2014: Go for a walk
    01.01.2015: sleep
    ...
```

In each cell there are several different dates with different years.
I want to order this in a table which shall look like this:

```
2013             |   2014           |     2015
_________________|__________________|__________
play video games | go for a walk    |   sleep
...                ....                 ....
```

I built a sql but it did not work as I want it to work.

SQL:

```
SELECT `COL 1` FROM `table 1` WHERE `COL 1` LIKE '%2013%'
```

The Problem is that this gives me the whole cell if there is a 2013.

Now I though that I need some kind of exception just to get the line of 2013, 
but I do not know how to accomplish this, can anybody help.

Comment: Don't store data like that, have one column for the date, and another column for the info.

Comment: Unfortunaly this is how the customer wants it

Comment: Poor customer, and poor you. That will only cause you lots of trouble, take longer time, and probably end up with more problems and bugs...

Comment: do you think it would be possible to like start 2013 minus 6 characters so I would have the starting point and end it if like a date format appears or if a years between 2013-2015 appears and that minus 6

Comment: What is your database?You could go for a dynamic pivot

Comment: database is phpmyadmin, what is dynamic pivot

Comment: Something like this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101862/mysql-pivot-table-dynamic-rows

Comment: phpadmin is not a database, it's a tool to handle database administration. So we guess that your database is MySQL.

Comment: Could you show some representative data?Do you have different months and days?

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are formatted uniformly, you could do:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(`COL 1`, 7, 4) = '2013'
```

If the table is large it will probably give performance issues though.

Comment: I got an empty result from that

Comment: You could try selecting the substring, to check it selects the year all right.

Comment: I did that but it gives me a list full of zeros

Comment: Did this SELECT SUBSTRING('COL 1', 7, 4) = '2013' FROM `table 1`

Comment: That makes sense, with respect to your previous result. Could you try `SELECT SUBSTRING('COL 1', 7, 4) FROM table_1`?